# How to create custom HTML elements

Tags: html, dom

I am doing this tutorial [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)

I simply copied and pasted the code below.

```
var XFoo = document.register('x-foo');
document.body.appendChild(new XFoo());
```

I immediatly get an error saying that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'register'
```

I do not know why nor what I am doing wrong. I am using the Chrome browser.

Comment: Direct quote from the article you linked: "Heads up! This article discusses APIs that are not yet fully standardized and still in flux. Be cautious when using experimental APIs in your own projects."

Comment: I noticed that but I would have assumed that it would have at least some kind of functionality otherwise they wouldn't have written the article

Answer (score 4):

I implemented Custom Elements in Chrome so I might be able to help.

Starting with Chrome 33, `document.register` has been renamed `document.registerElement`.

Up to Chrome 32, the most likely reason you would get that error is if the Experimental Web Platform Features flag is not enabled. Cut and paste chrome://flags into the Omnibox and hit enter to check. After changing flags, you have to restart your browser for the changes to take effect.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Only **firefox** and **chrome** are known to support it yet. If you are trying it in **IE**, **Safari** or **Opera** then you are out of luck.